# Ошибка передачи данных при переходе с ViewController на ViewController [xCode, SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть такая схема экранов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо с первого ViewController'a передать информацию на второй ViewController. Раньше, когда не было между ними Navigation Controller'a, я мог реализовать это следующим образом:
создаю переход с одного экрана на другой, и пишу следующий код:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Photos" {
            
            let imgView = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
            imgView.arrPhoto = self.addrPhotos
        
        }
    }
```

И так как Navigation Controller'a не было между ними, все работало замечательно, но мне понадобился Navigation Controller, и теперь у меня при переходе выдает ошибку, так как в коде указывается,             `let imgView = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController`
а переход осуществляется на Navigation Controller. Как возможно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так.

```
let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let imgView = navController.viewControllers.first as! CollectionViewController
imgView.arrPhoto = self.addrPhotos
```